# iPad Kernel panic, how do I interpret the crash report?

Tags: ipad

While using my app, one of my testers experiences a kernel panic. The report he's sending to me has the extension panic.crash, does anybody know how to interpret this type of file? It doesn't seem to contain a stack trace, at least not in the nomral .crash format.

Answer (score 0):

Normally crash logs are just text. I'll admit I've never seen a kernel panic from an iOS device.

And normally you save your .dSYM files so you can symbolicate crash logs (by dragging them into the Xcode Organizer window).